# CorePlot & Cocoapods for master head & new coming release branch 2.0

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, cocoapods

I'm trying to configure a **local pods** for pointing on **Coreplot master head** or **2.0 branch** (two differents podspec so).

The actual mode is using a **zip file** and **I don't know the transformation made manually on the framework**, but I want to point on the head and be able to switch on the branch 2.0, I created my pod (cf end of email) and here the result of the lint command :

## CorePlot (2.0)

```
- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  CorePlot/framework/Source/CPTAnimation.m:122:5: error: 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  CorePlot/framework/Source/CPTAnimation.m:122:5: error: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'

- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  CorePlot/framework/Source/CPTAnimation.m:458:9: error: 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode

- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  CorePlot/framework/Source/CPTAnimation.m:458:9: error: ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'
```

## CorePlot head

```
- ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  CorePlot/framework/Source/CPTLayer.m:8:9: fatal error: 'CorePlotProbes.h' file not found
```

Here is the pods

## Podfile

pod 'CorePlot', :path => 'specsLocalSpecFolder'

## Podfile

(This is the 2.0, switch for 1.0 in comment, I simplify the author, desc… for readibility reason)

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name     = 'CorePlot'
  s.version  = '2.0'
  s.license  = 'BSD'
  s.summary  = 'Cocoa plotting framework for Mac OS X and iOS.'
  s.homepage = 'https://github.com/core-plot'
  #s.source   = { :http => 'https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases/download/release_1.4/CorePlot_1.4.zip' }
  s.source   = {:git => "https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.git", :branch => "release-2.0" }#remove branch for 1.x
  s.author       = { "Name" => "email@email.com" }


  s.requires_arc = true#false for 1.x, true for 2.0
  s.platform = :ios  #for test not ncessary
  s.ios.deployment_target = '6.0'#test not ncessary

  s.description = 'Desc'

  s.source_files = 'framework/Source/*.{h,m}'
  s.exclude_files = '**/*{TestCase,Tests}.{h,m}'
  s.ios.source_files = 'framework/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h', 'framework/iPhoneOnly/*.{h,m}'
  s.osx.source_files = 'framework/CorePlot.h', 'framework/MacOnly/*.{h,m}'

  s.framework   = 'QuartzCore,Accelerate'#updated for 2.0

end
```

## Testing

pod spec lint specs/CorePlot.podspec  --verbose

Any help appreciated, I'll update the final code at the end to share it that would be usefull to integrate quickly a fix or test the impact of 2.0 branch.

Comment: What is this pod file for? Why don't you just use a git client, checkout the 2.0 branch and start working on it?

Comment: The goal is pointing with the pods easily to any tag or branch without having to clone and configure manually the project. Doing this without pods takes generally a lot of time even if you are used to do it (I'm a big fan of pods and a switcher for this :) ). And with pods I can commit files and reset easily (more easily than with a submodule)

Comment: You won't come around cloning the repository if you want to work with it. Configuration is not necessary. Just branch it and compile. Done. Looks to me as if there's a lot extra work involved with that pod stuff for no real benefit. Just my 2 cents.